# Understanding MYSQL composite index

Tags: mysql

I have been reading some code and come across `UNIQUE KEY User_name (User_name,Email)`

why user_name is repeated in this composite index? why not just `UNIQUE KEY (User_name,Email)`?

Comment: if you don't assign a key name, it is auto-assigned. Also be careful not to dupe up your key names during "creates" (from cut-n-paste) because that will error out. If you don't assign a name, you can always see them via `show create table myTableName` or `show indexes from myTableName;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a together unique index. When both fields are considered together their values cannot be repeated but individual fields may repeat.

For example there may be several entries in the  username column called *Tim*, and there maybe several entires in the email field named tim@example.com however there can be only one `username=tim, email=tim@example.com`

If you want usernames to be unique (which is usually the case) you need to make that column unique on it's own (you can also make it the primary key).

Answer (score 2):

The first `User_name` is the name of the key, it does not refer to the column. You can name your index whatever you want, for instance:

```
UNIQUE KEY uniq_user_name_email (User_name, Email)
```

The index name is not mandatory, but it is useful if you have to run commands on this index later on, such as a `DROP INDEX uniq_user_name_email`.

Here is the complete syntax from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] [index_type](index_col_name,...) [index_option]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the name of the index. You can change the name according to your need.

If you are thinking about the order of indexes, that does matter.

The ordering of a two-column index is therefore like the ordering of a telephone directory: it is first sorted by surname, then by first name. That means that a two-column index does not support searching on the second column alone; that would be like searching a telephone directory by first name.